# Dump raw XML to debug Grails REST calls

Tags: xml, grails

We need to dump the raw XML for troubleshooting data dependant issues on a Grails 1.2 app. In the UrlMappings we have "parseRequest:true". The following does not get me what I'm looking for, any other options? Note that we need this on a production machine, so fiddler or similar proxy based solutions suitable for development are not an option

```
def beforeInterceptor = {
    println "#"*99
    println "Executing action $actionName with params=$params"
    println request.inputStream.dump()
    //println request.inputStream.text // java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    println request.XML
}
```

Comment: And being able to dump the response XML would be nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, when you do request.XML you should receive an XmlSlurper object.  So this *should* get what you want.

```
def beforeInterceptor = {
   def xml = request.XML
   def xmlString = new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(new StringWriter())).print(xml)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that `request.XML` is of type groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild and it has a crappy toString() override. So the solution is [here](http://btiernay.wordpress.com/2009/11/13/serializing-groovy-util-slurpersupport-nodechild/), put this in your **bootstrap**

```
NodeChild.metaClass.toXmlString = {
    def self = delegate
    new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
        delegate.mkp.xmlDeclaration() // Use this if you want an XML declaration
        delegate.out << self
    }.toString()
}
```

And this in the controller:

```
def beforeInterceptor = {
    println "#"*99
    log.info "REST CALL [${request.serverName}${request.forwardURI}?${request.queryString}] with [$request.method] action [$actionName]"
    println request.XML.toXmlString()
}
```

Comment: when i add the first code to Bootstrap.groovy it doesn't compile! do you have an idea why? after NodeChild it says it expect a ,;or )