# Grails populate params with XML from POST request

Tags: grails

I have a RestFull grails api that i expose through grails Controller.
I need to automatically bind the xml data sent in a POST request.
I don't think using groovy `bindData(object,params)` works as the `params` reference seems not having the xml elements. i use the `parseRequest=true` in the UrlMappings but yet the `params` Object does'nt have the xml elements.

am i missing some other config so that my params object get automatically populated with the xml body elements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it seems the right way to do it is to use:

```
request.reader.text
```

to get the raw xml. the other methods were not successfull for me.

Comment: How about populating the params?  That's in the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

`request.XML` is the object holding the Elements parsed from the XML request

Have a look at the [request](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Servlet%20API/request.html) variable available to your controllers.

Comment: yes i know about request.XML but it has a serious problem described in link. i can't get request.XML.toString() in a correct format. and the solutions here are not helpfull http://stackoverflow.com/q/7096648/497984

Comment: do you know a way to get the request.XML string? i tried request.reader.text but this one also caused problems when i send POST request from a remote client. some error like getInputStream() has already been called.

Comment: so, you want the raw XML ? not the parsed one ?

Comment: the raw is better for me as i want to do some Generic object binding work with it. I wrote a binding method that do binding of any xml string without knowing the real structure of the xml. that's why i need the raw xml. a clean way to override `request.XML.toString()` to get the raw xml would be very usefull.

Comment: if you want the raw XML, try not to import `grails.converters.*` and use the `parseRequest=false` in your mapping. If this still not work, disable xml mime type in config

Comment: I tried all 3 suggestions but yet it still doesn't work! strange why the request.XML.toString() gives this garbage text. Any further help is much appreciated.

Comment: btw i'm using grails 2.0.3. does this version have this annoying request.XML.toString() garbage issue?

Comment: [last chance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046721/accessing-the-raw-body-of-a-put-or-post-request) :-)

Comment: thank you :) but it seems using `request.reader.text` solved the issue. i think this solution is simpler.